# method in @Controller of SpringMVC being called twice, happens only on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, spring-mvc, controller

I have a problem as my method in @Controller of SpringMVC is called twice by two different thread and it only happened on IE, not in Firefox nor Chrome.  Has anyone ever had this same experience and is there any solution to this problem?  Thank you

Comment: can you be more specific? Which method gets executed twice? What is the scope of your controller? Maybe even provide a bit of code.

Comment: I Guess you are dealing with an ajax call. May be ajax is going twice. Since this is happening only in IE, you need to use fiddler or IE developer tool for the same.